# glass rod and wool

Tags: electrostatics

when the glass rod is rubbed with wool, it loses electrons and gets positively charged, while the wool gains those electrons and gets negatively charged.

we all now that but where electron store in wool ? do they store in surface or they can go deeper ?

dose electron goes to atom or just stay between molecule ?

why glass with positive charge do not go to chemical reaction with its enviroment?

Answer (score 1):

The excess electrons reside in organic molecules near the surface of the wool (or silk).

The excess electrons stay associated with individual molecules.

The postively charged glass rod is, in fact, more likely to undergo chemical reactions due to its positive charge, but there are relatively few depleted electron levels so the effect is small.